# #define header error message when trying to make code look clean

Tags: header, macros, c-preprocessor

My macro doesn't fit nicely on the screen without scrolling, so I want to break it up so it reads nicely.  It works fine if it looks like this:

```
#define longMacro(ptr, idx0, idx1, idx2, idx3, idx4, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4) (*((ptr) + (idx0) * (dim1) * (dim2) * (dim3) * (dim4) + (idx1) * (dim2) * (dim3) * (dim4) + (idx2) * (dim3) * (dim4) + (idx3) * (dim4) + (idx4)))
```

but when I try to break it up like this:

```
#define longMacro(ptr, idx0, idx1, idx2, idx3, idx4, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4) 
    (*((ptr) + (idx0) * (dim1) * (dim2) * (dim3) * (dim4) 
    + (idx1) * (dim2) * (dim3) * (dim4) + (idx2) * (dim3) * (dim4) 
    + (idx3) * (dim4) + (idx4)))
```

I get these errors

> error: expected `)' before ‘+’ token
>    error: expected `)' before ‘+’ token
>    error: expected `)' before ‘+’ token
>    error: expected `)' before ‘+’ token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you're missing a "\" before the end of each line

```
#define longMacro(ptr, idx0, idx1, idx2, idx3, idx4, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4) \
    (*((ptr) + (idx0) * (dim1) * (dim2) * (dim3) * (dim4) \
    + (idx1) * (dim2) * (dim3) * (dim4) + (idx2) * (dim3) * (dim4) \
    + (idx3) * (dim4) + (idx4)))
```